# Change Categorical Variable levels to What I provide/Combine levels two categorical variables

Tags: pandas

The following situation often arises from my data analysis. Say I have two vectors of data, x and y, from some observations. x has more data points and thus contains some values that are not observed in y. Now I want to make them into categorical variables.

```
x=['a','b','c','d','e']  #data points
y =['a','c','e']         #data of the same nature as x but with fewer data points  

fx = pandas.Categorical.from_array(x)
fy = pandas.Categorical.from_array(y)

print fx.index
print fy.index

Categorical: 
array([a, b, c, d, e], dtype=object)
Levels (5): Index([a, b, c, d, e], dtype=object) Categorical: 
array([a, c, e], dtype=object)
Levels (3): Index([a, c, e], dtype=object)
```

I see that now they have different levels and labels mean different things (1 means b in fx but c in fy).

This obviously make it hard for code that work with both fx and fy as they expect fx.labels and fy.labels have the same encoding/meaning.

But I do not see how to 'normalize' fx and fy so that they have the same levels and `fx.lables` and `fy.lables` have the same coding. `fy.labels = fx.lables` clearly does not work. As the following demonstrates that it changes the meanings of the labels [a c e] becomes [a b c].

```
fy.levels = fx.levels
print fy

Categorical: 
array([a, b, c], dtype=object)
Levels (5): Index([a, b, c, d, e], dtype=object)
```

Does anyone have any ideas?

Another related scenario is that I have an existing, known index, and want to factor the data into this index. For example, I know that every data point has to take one of the five values [a, b, c, d, e] and I already have an index `Index([a, b, c, d, e], dtype=object)` and I want to factorize vector y=['a','c','e'] into a Categoricial variable with `Index([a, b, c, d, e], dtype=object)` as its levels. I am not sure how it can be done either and would like someone who knows to give some clues.

P.S It is possible but cumbersome to do such things in R.

Thanks,
Tom

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the `get_indexer()` method can be used to create the index array:

```
x=['a','b','c','d','e']  #data points
y =['a','c','e']         #data of the same nature as x but with fewer data points  
idx = pd.Index(pd.unique(x+y))
cx = pd.Categorical(idx.get_indexer(x), idx)
cy = pd.Categorical(idx.get_indexer(y), idx)
```

Answer (score 4):

```
In [6]: fxd = {fx.levels[i]: i for i in range(len(fx.levels))}

In [7]: fy.labels = [fxd[v] for v in fy]

In [8]: fy.levels = fx.levels

In [9]: fy
Out[9]: 
Categorical: 
array([a, c, e], dtype=object)
Levels (5): Index([a, b, c, d, e], dtype=object)
```

Comment: I get the general idea, but I think there is a bug. In [6], it should be range(len(fx.levels)).

Comment: Oops. Thanks for the catch. Fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding Garrett's answer: in my version of pandas (0.20.3) `fx.levels` raises an AttributeError: 'Categorical' object has no attribute 'levels', but what works is:

```
missing_levels = set(fx) - set(fy)
fy = fy.add_categories(missing_levels)
```

or with `inplace=True` (a bit faster):

```
missing_levels = set(fx) - set(fy)
fy.add_categories(missing_levels, inplace=True)
```