# How to apply custom column order (on Categorical) to pandas boxplot?

Tags: python, pandas, boxplot, categorical-data

EDIT: this question arose back in 2013 with pandas ~0.13 and was obsoleted by direct support for boxplot somewhere between version 0.15-0.18 (as per [@Cireo's late answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44057503/202229); also pandas greatly improved support for categorical since this was asked.)

---

I can get a `boxplot` of a salary column in a pandas DataFrame...

```
train.boxplot(column='Salary', by='Category', sym='')
```

...however I can't figure out how to **define the index-order used on column 'Category' - I want to supply my own custom order**, according to another criterion:

```
category_order_by_mean_salary = train.groupby('Category')['Salary'].mean().order().keys()
```

How can I apply my custom column order to the boxplot columns? (other than ugly kludging the column names with a prefix to force ordering)

'Category' is a string (really, should be a categorical, but this was back in 0.13, where categorical was a third-class citizen) column taking 27 distinct values: `['Accounting & Finance Jobs','Admin Jobs',...,'Travel Jobs']`. So it can be easily factorized with `pd.Categorical.from_array()`

On inspection, the limitation is inside **`pandas.tools.plotting.py:boxplot()`**, which converts the column object without allowing ordering:

- [pandas.core.frame.py.boxplot()](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/frame.py) is a passthrough to
- **[pandas.tools.plotting.py:boxplot()](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/master/pandas/tools/plotting.py)**
  which instantiates ...
- [matplotlib.pyplot.py:boxplot()](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/lib/matplotlib/pyplot.py) which instantiates ...
- [matplotlib.axes.py:boxplot()](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/lib/matplotlib/axes.py)

I suppose I could either hack up a custom version of pandas boxplot(), or reach into the internals of the object. And also file an enhance request.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Hard to say how to do this without a working example. My first guess would be to just add an integer column with the orders that you want.

A simple, brute-force way would be to add each boxplot one at a time.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(37,4), columns=list('ABCD'))
columns_my_order = ['C', 'A', 'D', 'B']
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for position, column in enumerate(columns_my_order):
    ax.boxplot(df[column], positions=[position])

ax.set_xticks(range(position+1))
ax.set_xticklabels(columns_my_order)
ax.set_xlim(xmin=-0.5)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Added details for you, and ideas on workarounds. Adding a separate standalone integer column doesn't give a decent graph because now your column labels are (illegible) integers, not text. (Kludging a text prefix into Category names to force custom sort-order is maybe the fastest hack. But still ugly)

Comment: [pandas DataFrame cannot handle a Categorical column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15356433/how-to-generate-pandas-dataframe-column-of-categorical-from-string-column), unlike R.

Comment: not where I was headed. I typically just use `apply` with a hard-coded lookup table. see my edited response for a different approach, though.

Comment: Duh! Why didn't I think of that! Good idea.

Answer (score 6):

EDIT: this is the right answer after direct support was added somewhere between version 0.15-0.18

---

**tl;dr**: for recent pandas - use `positions` argument to [boxplot](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.boxplot.html#matplotlib.pyplot.boxplot).

Adding a separate answer, which perhaps could be another question - feedback appreciated.

I wanted to add a custom column order within a groupby, which posed many problems for me.  In the end, I had to avoid trying to use `boxplot` from a `groupby` object, and instead go through each subplot myself to provide explicit positions.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame()
df['GroupBy'] = ['g1', 'g2', 'g3', 'g4'] * 6
df['PlotBy'] = [chr(ord('A') + i) for i in xrange(24)]
df['SortBy'] = list(reversed(range(24)))
df['Data'] = [i * 10 for i in xrange(24)]

# Note that this has no effect on the boxplot
df = df.sort_values(['GroupBy', 'SortBy'])
for group, info in df.groupby('GroupBy'):
    print 'Group: %r\n%s\n' % (group, info)

# With the below, cannot use
#  - sort data beforehand (not preserved, can't access in groupby)
#  - categorical (not all present in every chart)
#  - positional (different lengths and sort orders per group)
# df.groupby('GroupBy').boxplot(layout=(1, 5), column=['Data'], by=['PlotBy'])

fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, df.GroupBy.nunique(), sharey=True)
for ax, (g, d) in zip(axes, df.groupby('GroupBy')):
    d.boxplot(column=['Data'], by=['PlotBy'], ax=ax, positions=d.index.values)
plt.show()
```

Within my final code, it was even slightly more involved to determine positions because I had multiple data points for each sortby value, and I ended up having to do the below:

```
to_plot = data.sort_values([sort_col]).groupby(group_col)
for ax, (group, group_data) in zip(axes, to_plot):
    # Use existing sorting
    ordering = enumerate(group_data[sort_col].unique())
    positions = [ind for val, ind in sorted((v, i) for (i, v) in ordering)]
    ax = group_data.boxplot(column=[col], by=[plot_by], ax=ax, positions=positions)
```

Comment: Well the original question's been closed for years, why not add a new question for this answer? Specify pandas 0.20+

Comment: Wasn't sure as to the etiquette of posting a question then answering it yourself =/

Comment: that's perfectly ok. Also in this case desirable - this question has become obsolete at some point by pandas 0.19

Answer (score 3):

Actually I got stuck with the same question. And I solved it by making a map and reset the xticklabels, with code as follows:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"A":["d","c","d","c",'d','c','a','c','a','c','a','c']})
df['val']=(np.random.rand(12))
df['B']=df['A'].replace({'d':'0','c':'1','a':'2'})
ax=df.boxplot(column='val',by='B')
ax.set_xticklabels(list('dca'))
```

Comment: Please note that `set_xticklabels()` will give a wrong result as it's just overwriting the existing labels. `set_xticklabels(list('dca'))` is not moving the value of label d' to first place as you and OP intended instead, re-labelling whatever the first label was as 'd'

Answer (score 2):

Note that pandas can now create categorical columns.  If you don't mind having all the columns present in your graph, or trimming them appropriately, you can do something like the below:

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/categorical.html

```
df['Category'] = df['Category'].astype('category', ordered=True)
```

Recent pandas also appears to allow `positions` to pass all the way through from frame to axes.

- https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/frame.py
- https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/plotting/_core.py
- https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/lib/matplotlib/pyplot.py
- https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/lib/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py

Comment: The link said 0.15, but I was suspicious of that.  I'm not sure if the feature was fully integrated at that point.  I was able to do all of this in `0.19.2`

Comment: Thanks for checking.

Answer (score 2):

It might sound kind of silly, but many of the plot allow you to determine the order. For example:

**Library & dataset**

```
import seaborn as sns
df = sns.load_dataset('iris')
```

**Specific order**

```
p1=sns.boxplot(x='species', y='sepal_length', data=df, order=["virginica", "versicolor", "setosa"])
sns.plt.show()
```

Comment: Not silly at all, this is the perfect solution for people using seaborn.

Answer (score 1):

If you're not happy with the default column order in your boxplot, you can change it to a specific order by setting the *column* parameter in the boxplot function.

check the two examples below:

```
np.random.seed(0)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(37,4), columns=list('ABCD'))

##
plt.figure()
df.boxplot()
plt.title("default column order")

##
plt.figure()
df.boxplot(column=['C','A', 'D', 'B'])
plt.title("Specified column order")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use the new **positions=** attribute:

`df.boxplot(column=['Data'], by=['PlotBy'], positions=df.index.values)`

Comment: cc: @Cireo you might like to edit your answer for clarity

Answer (score 0):

This can be resolved by applying a categorical order. You can decide on the ranking yourself. I'll give an example with days of week.

- Provide categorical order to weekday

  ```
  #List categorical variables in correct order
  weekday = ['Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday','Sunday']
  #Assign the above list to category ranking
  wDays = pd.api.types.CategoricalDtype(ordered= True, categories=Weekday)
  #Apply this to the specific column in DataFrame
  df['Weekday'] = df['Weekday'].astype(wDays)
  # Then generate your plot
  plt.figure(figsize = [15, 10])
  sns.boxplot(data = flights_samp, x = 'Weekday', y = 'Y Axis Variable', color = colour)
  ```