# Reorder Catagorical X axis ticks Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a question, that I think is simple to solve, yet I cannot seem to do it!
I would like to make a simple plot using matplotlib where the x-axis values are categorical. Below is the code I am using:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = pd.DataFrame()
data['lineID'] = [1]*5 + [2]*5
data['value'] = ['C', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A']
data['chain1'] = [0,1,2,3,4,0,1,2,3,4]
data['chain2'] = [1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5]


f, ax = plt.subplots(1, len(data['lineID'].unique()))
for idx, lid in enumerate(data['lineID'].unique()):
    _ = data.loc[data['lineID']==lid, :]
    ax[idx].plot((_['value'], _['value']),
                  (_['chain1'], _['chain2']))
```

Now, this produces a nice plot, as shown below.

[image: Figure 1]

However, I would like to rearrange the X axis to say 'C', 'B', 'A'. I have tried to set the xticks like so,

```
f, ax = plt.subplots(1, len(data['lineID'].unique()))
for idx, lid in enumerate(data['lineID'].unique()):
    _ = data.loc[data['lineID']==lid, :]
    ax[idx].plot((_['value'], _['value']),
                  (_['chain1'], _['chain2']))
    ax[idx].set_xticks(['C', 'B', 'A'])
```

However, this does rearrange the labels (see figure 2 below), but the data is still plotting as it is in figure 1. 
[image: Figure 2]

Does anyone know how I can solve this? I thought to re-label then one would use `ax.set_xlabels` as opposed to `ax.set_xticks`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Something like this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15541440/how-to-apply-custom-column-order-to-pandas-boxplot

Comment: Works well, thanks cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ.