# Categorical Variables In A Pandas Dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, categorical-data

I am working my way through Wes's Python For Data Analysis, and I've run into a strange problem that is not addressed in the book.

In the code below, based on page 199 of his book, I create a dataframe and then use `pd.cut()` to create `cat_obj`. According to the book, `cat_obj` is

> "a special Categorical object. You can treat it like an array of
>   strings indicating the bin name; internally it contains a levels array
>   indicating the distinct category names along with a labeling for the
>   ages data in the labels attribute"

Awesome! However, if I use the exact same `pd.cut()` code (In [5] below) to create a new column of the dataframe (called `df['cat']`), that column is not treated as a special *categorical variable* but simply as a regular pandas series.

How, then, do I create a column in a dataframe that is treated as a categorical variable?

```
In [4]:

import pandas as pd

raw_data = {'name': ['Miller', 'Jacobson', 'Ali', 'Milner', 'Cooze', 'Jacon', 'Ryaner', 'Sone', 'Sloan', 'Piger', 'Riani', 'Ali'], 
        'score': [25, 94, 57, 62, 70, 25, 94, 57, 62, 70, 62, 70]}
df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['name', 'score'])

bins = [0, 25, 50, 75, 100]
group_names = ['Low', 'Okay', 'Good', 'Great']

In [5]:
cat_obj = pd.cut(df['score'], bins, labels=group_names)
df['cat'] = pd.cut(df['score'], bins, labels=group_names)
In [7]:

type(cat_obj)
Out[7]:
pandas.core.categorical.Categorical
In [8]:

type(df['cat'])
Out[8]:
pandas.core.series.Series
```

Comment: all columns of a DataFrame are going to be Series, what behavior are you looking for that this doesn't achieve?

Comment: Things like df['cat'].levels don't work, but cat_obj.levels does

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to generate pandas DataFrame column of Categorical from string column?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15356433/how-to-generate-pandas-dataframe-column-of-categorical-from-string-column)

Comment: You could always cast it as a <pd.Categorical> when needed: 
    pd.Categorical.from_array(df['cat']).levels

Comment: This is currently worked on in pandas: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/pull/7217

Comment: I just verified that your code works in Pandas 0.15 to get categories.  E.g. print df['cat'] returns back "Name: cat, dtype: category Categories (4, object): [Low < Okay < Good < Great]".  You can then manipulate the categories like this: df = df.groupby('cat').size()

Answer (score 1):

It might be happening because of this kind of behaviour by setter-:

Sample getter and setter-

```
class a:
    x = 1
    @property
    def p(self):
        return int(self.x)

    @p.setter
    def p(self,v):
        self.x = v
t = 1.32
a().p = 1.32


print type(t) --> <type 'float'>
print type(a().p) --> <type 'int'>
```

For now `df` only accepts `Series data` and its setter converts `Categorial data` into `Series`. `df` categorial support is due in Next Pandas release.

Answer (score 0):

Right now, you can't have categorical data in a Series or DataFrame object, but this functionality will be implemented in [Pandas 0.15](http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/categorical.html) (due in September).

Answer (score 0):

From http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/categorical.html, **from pandas 0.15 onwards**

Specify dtype="category" when constructing a Series:

```
In [1]: s = pd.Series(["a","b","c","a"], dtype="category")

In [2]: s
Out[2]: 
0    a
1    b
2    c
3    a
dtype: category
Categories (3, object): [a, b, c]
```

You can then add this to an existing series.

Or convert an existing Series or column to a category dtype:

```
In [3]: df = pd.DataFrame({"A":["a","b","c","a"]})

In [4]: df["B"] = df["A"].astype('category')

In [5]: df
Out[5]: 
   A  B
0  a  a
1  b  b
2  c  c
3  a  a
```